# can install TeamViewer 10 & 11 on Macintosh at same time?

Tags: macos, teamviewer

Teamviewer 11 is installed onto a Macintosh via an installer application.  I *think* Teamviewer 10 is erased as the new version is installed.

And that's not counting any resources in System Folders (e.g. "`/Library/`") that get installed or overwritten.

I know they can't run at the same time, but does anyone know if Teamviewer 10 & Teamviewer 11 can co-exist on a Macintosh at the same time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long story short, no. TeamViewer can be downgraded to an earlier version, but can't install two versions side by side. It will overwrite each time you attempt to install it.

Two potential options to solve your problem:

- Find a portable edition of one or both versions. TeamViewer [does not make a portable version for Mac](https://www.teamviewer.com/en/download/previous-versions/), but there might be a portable executable that someone has created somewhere out on the internet.
- Run the other version in a virtual machine. You can use [Parallels](http://www.parallels.com/) to set this up.

Comment: my mistake.  I swear I read install on Windows and Mac at same time.  Sorry for that deleting.